# Set property if exists in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of type `Derp`:

```
public class Derp
{
    public bool Valid;
    public int SomeValue;
    public int MoreValues;
    public int EvenMoreValues;
    public int ThereAreManyValues;
}

List<Derp> a = new List<Derp>();
List<Derp> b = new List<Derp>();
/// Populate both

var c = a.Intersect(b).Select(x=> { x.Valid = true; return x; });
```

I need to set `Valid` to true if `b` exists in `a` and keep all values in `a`. I can understand that the snippet above only keeps the intersected objects, but I need to retain `a`.

I've tried other funny things too (`var c = a.Where(x => b.Contains(x)).Sel...`) but I don't think I understand the List methods enough to solve this one.

Comment: Linq is not a good tool for side effects. Dump the idea of using linq and write a foreach loop. Or just write a linq query to query the objects you need, then use foreach to update it.

Comment: Curious, why do you say that (Linq is not a good tool)?

Comment: I said Linq is not a good tool for **side effects** (doesn't mean Linq is not a good tool). Full form of linq is Language-Integrated **Query**. As the name suggests it should be used only for querying data, not updating it. [Bonus reading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: Cool, can't believe I'm so blind to the q of Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
b.ForEach(x => {if (a.Contains(x)) {x.Valid = true;} });
```

The above works. However, do take note of @SriramSakthivel's comments and reconsider your approach if possible.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XIEXT31266)

Comment: I've decided to implement the foreach loop instead. Your answer doesn't seem to different from it though.

Comment: Yep, that's a better solution rather than using Linq. In fact, except for `List`, I don't think any other collections have a `ForEach` method associated.